# How to refresh a PHP variable on every part of the page after success submit event of ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**Updated**

I am sending a unique variable through ajax and needs to refresh this variable every time when i submit the form again

my code looks something like this

```
 function refresh_fun() {
 /******  PHP  ******/
 <?php 
 $GLOBALS['uni_sub'] = uniqid(); // wants to refresh it  
 ?>
}
 /****** HTML *******/
 <input type="hidden" name="uni_sub" value="<?php echo $uni_sub;?>"> //needs to refresh it too in order to get the same unique refreshed variable 

 /*****  Ajax ******/
  success: function(response)
  {
    refresh_fun(); // this function should change the php variable
   }
```

Comment: Where is Ajax ?

Comment: You tagged *AJAX* but there are no sign of usage of it?

Comment: "_Every ms_"?? Are you talking about milliseconds here?

Comment: is there need of ajax code ? because i just need to refresh the variable ajax is used to submit the form and i talked about ajax cause i want you to know that page is not refreshing

Comment: yes its millisecond

Comment: now i have removed ajax tag

Comment: Ok, just curious: what kind of website is this? Why would you need to update a PHP variable every millisecond?

Comment: If you intend to do something repetitively you can combine *[setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)* with a function wrapping an **AJAX** code inside it

Comment: when your need is, to update the unique ID per form submit, why would you want to send this every millisecond? or even every second? this produces a lot of unneeded traffic. instead, you should use the submit action, to first get a unique id from the server and then submit the form.

Comment: well exactly this is i want .. wants to change the php variable value on every success submittion of form can you please show this through code

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a UI that would show display info every time local variable values change, you could try interval timer in javascript or use REACT or Vue. If you mean a change in PHP variables to reflect on page (without page refresh), then you definitely do not want making requests to the server every millisecond. You need to "push" those updates each second maybe. Check about websocket

Comment: i don't think websocket will help me . i just want that the value inside this php variable should keep changing so that every time i will submit form i will get a unique id to submit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax polling that will look like this:

```
//js
var firstid = 0;
function ajaxpolling(){
   $.post('gogetmyuniqueid.php', function(idhere) {
       if (firstid != idhere) { // do changes on input if there's update
          firstid = idhere;
          $("#myhiddeninput").val(idhere);
       }
   });
}
setTimeout(ajaxpolling(),5000);
```

But i would suggest using SSE:

```
// js
var firstid = 0;
var source = new EventSource("gogetmyuniqueid.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    if (firstid != event.data) { // do changes on input if there's update
         firstid = event.data;
         $("#myhiddeninput").val(event.data);
    }
};
```

Server-side (PHP) using SSE:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

echo "data: {uniqueid()}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Comment: can i  change value only one time just after succession of a javascript function

Comment: i think you should clarify one thing here..whats inside the function uniqueid()? i only assume that it has a query something like this "SELECT id from tbl order by id desc LIMIT 1".  but if you want to change the value of your hidden input after the "on submit" event. you could just change it on your success event (assume your using ajax)

Comment: exactly how to change it after success event??

Comment: on your server side (assume like "insert.php"). you need to return uniqueid() as a response there.

Comment: means need to load insert.php file on every success event?

Comment: no your "insert.php" should return uniqueid();

Comment: when your "onsubmit" fires on "insert.php"..."insert.php" should return (echo out) uniqueid()